# Syntax error message with GW-BASIC

Tags: basic, gw-basic

I am currently stymied by the following error message from GW-BASIC:

```
Syntax error in 450
Ok
450 STEP=0
```

Here is the context:

```
400 ON KEY(13) GOSUB 590 ' right arrow key makes direction clockwise
410 ON KEY(12) GOSUB 610 ' left arrow key makes direction counter-clockwise
420 ON KEY(11) GOSUB 630 ' up arrow makes faster
430 ON KEY(14) GOSUB 670 ' down arrow makes slower
440 '
450 STEP=0
460 OUT DATAPORT, 0
```

I have tried the assignment with and without the LET keyword, with the same results. I can't see anything wrong with my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`STEP` is a reserved GWBasic keyword. Change the name to something else, like `MYSTEP` or something.

Comment: Thanks.  Silly me.  I looked at that code for an hour, and never saw it.  Sheesh.  Thanks again.